# Getting gibberish in postman when creating records in online database with mule 4

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, dataweave, mule4

I am using phpmyadmin online database. I have applied client_id and client_secret API manager security and deployed to cloudhub.

Initially, I was able to fetch or update data in database but after deploying to cloudhub and ran in postman got this below error.

Its a put method, with body
{
"source":
{
"CustomerId" : "5",
"Name" : "Sam"

```
},
"destination":{
    "CustomerId" : "4",
    "Name" : "Jassie"
}
```

}

This is the query set as a variable.
"SELECT CustomerId,Country FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId IN " ++ "(" ++ "'" ++ payload.source.CustomerId ++ "'" ++ "," ++ "'" ++ payload.destination.CustomerId ++ "'" ++ ")"

{
"message": ""org.mule.weave.v2.exception.UnexpectedFunctionCallTypesException: You called the function '++' with these arguments: \n  1: String ("SELECT CustomerId,Country FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId IN ('")\n  2: Null (null)\n\nBut it expects one of these combinations:\n  (Array, Array)\n  (Date, Time)\n  (Date, LocalTime)\n  (Date, TimeZone)\n  (LocalDateTime, TimeZone)\n  (LocalTime, Date)\n  (LocalTime, TimeZone)\n  (Object, Object)\n  (String, String)\n  (Time, Date)\n  (TimeZone, LocalDateTime)\n  (TimeZone, Date)\n  (TimeZone, LocalTime)\n\n6| "SELECT CustomerId,Country FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId IN " ++ "(" ++ "'" ++ payload.source.CustomerId++ "'" ++ "," ++ "'" ++ payload.destination.CustomerId++ "'" ++ ")"\n   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\nTrace:\n  at ++ (line: 6, column: 1)\n  at ++ (line: 6, column: 75)\n  at ++ (line: 6, column: 103)\n  at ++ (line: 6, column: 110)\n  at ++ (line: 6, column: 117)\n  at ++ (line: 6, column: 124)\n  at ++ (line: 6, column: 157)\n  at main (line: 6, column: 164)\n" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0\noutput application/java\n---\n//"(" ++ "'" ++ payload.source.CustomerId++ "'" ++ "," ++ "'" ++ payload.destination.CustomerId++ "'" ++ ")"\n\n"SELECT CustomerId,Country FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId IN " ++ "(" ++ "'" ++ payload.source.CustomerId++ "'" ++ "," ++ "'" ++ payload.destination.CustomerId++ "'" ++ ")""."
}

Comment: Why do you set the query using string concatenation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this...

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
"SELECT CustomerId,Country FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId IN ('" ++ 
(payload.source.CustomerId as String default "")++ "', '" ++ 
(payload.destination.CustomerId as String default "") ++ "')"
```

Using output application/java or application/json depends on that functionality you'll using this for. The error you are facing is probably due to null value that you are sending. Defaulting it to "" will avoid the dataWeave failure.

Also, always try to club as many hardcodes string values inside a pair of "" as possible.

Comment: I don't have null values in tables but I tried same code and deployed on cloudhub, it worked fine. Thank you Satyam.

Comment: You can mark this as correct answer if this works, :)

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it looks like you are trying to construct query from CustomerId which can be wrapped inside source or destination. The code you have had some null "" values which is not acceptable while concatenating.

Here is how I would construct the DW by importing string module.

```
%dw 2.0
import unwrap from dw::core::Strings
output application/java
---
"SELECT CustomerId,Country FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId IN " ++ "(" ++ unwrap(write(payload..CustomerId  , "application/json", {"indent": false}), "")  ++ ")"
```

Here is the sample request and response.
[image]

Comment: This is working on local but with cloudhub url in postman, I am getting same payload as above with 500 Server Error. Locally. I am able get correct payload but on cloudhub something going wrong. Also, there are no null values in database (online phpmyadmin)

Comment: Is this the same payload you are sending in postman? This error will occur when there is no CustomerId in the payload.

Comment: Yes. Its same payload. I have deployed again cloudhub and tried. Its working fine. Thanks